# Why here StartCorotine() is necessary

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirePistol : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject TheGun;
    public GameObject MuzzleFlash;
    public AudioSource GunFire;
    public bool IsFiring = false;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            if (IsFiring == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FiringPistol());
            }
        }

    }

    IEnumerator FiringPistol ()
    {
        IsFiring = true;
        TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PistolShot");
        MuzzleFlash.SetActive(true);
        MuzzleFlash.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("MuzzleAnim");
        GunFire.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        IsFiring = false;
    }
}
```

I am writing a gun mechanic And
I wonder why we need 
`yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);`  .What is the difference without this command  .It's really unnecessary to write this code coz the time is short .Afterall , will it be an error like scene crash after i deleting this code ?Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Every method returning [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) **has** to contain at least one [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) statement. In Unity you **have** to use [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) to run an `IEnumerator` as [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

---

In your specific case: So you can delay your code by `0.5` seconds!

It is short but `0.5` is about 30 frames!

Someone using e.g. something like [AutoClicker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orphamielautoclicker) could jam the fire key each frame so he would cause significantly more damage then someone playing "normal" (due to physical limitations of your keyboard and finger ;) )

You are just avoiding that and limit down firing to a maximum of 2x per second.

In general - as usual - there are multiple ways to achieve that and you could go without Coroutines entirely but it makes coding so much cleaner and easier to maintain then doing everything in `Update`!

---

As some alternative examples for simple delays as here you could also either do a simple timer in `Update`

```c#
private float timer;

void Update () 
{
    if(timer > 0)
    {
        // reduce the timer by time passed since last frame
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else 
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            FiringPistol();
            timer = 0.5f;
        }
    }
}

void FiringPistol()
{
    TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PistolShot");
    MuzzleFlash.SetActive(true);
    MuzzleFlash.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("MuzzleAnim");
    GunFire.Play();
}
```

or you can also use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) with a given delay.

```c#
bool canFire;

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && canFire)
    {
        FiringPistol();
    }
}

void FiringPistol()
{
    TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PistolShot");
    MuzzleFlash.SetActive(true);
    MuzzleFlash.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("MuzzleAnim");
    GunFire.Play();

    Invoke(nameof(AfterCooldown), 0.5f);
}

void AfterCooldown()
{
    canFire = true;
}
```

---

In general btw you should store the `Animation` references to not use `GetComponent` over and over again:

```c#
// if possible already reference these via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Animation theGunAnimation;
[SerializeField] private Animation muzzleFlashAnimation;

private void Awake()
{
    // as fallback get them on runtime
    // since this is a fallback and in best case you already referenced these via the Inspector
    // we can save a bit of resources and use GetComponent
    // only in the case the fields are not already set
    // otherwise we can skip using GetComponent as we already have a reference
    if(!theGunAnimation) theGunAnimation = TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>();
    if(!muzzleFlashAnimation) muzzleFlashAnimation = MuzzleFlash.GetComponent<Animation>();
}
```

then later you reuse them

```c#
theGunAnimation.Play("PistolShot");
MuzzleFlash.SetActive(true);
muzzleFlashAnimation.Play("MuzzleAnim");
GunFire.Play();
```

Comment: Really good answer but I think he was not referring to this ! If you declare a Coroutine (IEnumerator returning function) you NEED to have at least one yield, or it won't compile.

Comment: @Jichael partially you might be right but `It's really unnecessary to write this code coz the time is short` also sounded like the question is in general what it is good for

Comment: @derHugo your answer is detailed and clear ! thank you so much !

Comment: @derHugo Could you tell me what is this:if(!theGunAnimation) theGunAnimation  ? Please. I dont understand this sentence of code      .And also , when we set the timer  . Time -= delta.time -->is that mean the delta.time is 0.5f everytime coz  it will be minused when It goes to 0.5f .Is the value of delta.time fixed?

Comment: the value of [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is as I said the time passed since last frame. `if(!theGunAnimation) theGunAnimation = TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>();` uses `GetComponent` just as you did before - but only in the case you didn't reference it already anyway via the Inspector => saves resources in case you already have the reference

Comment: @derHugo What's the difference between `if(!theGunAnimation) theGunAnimation = TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>();` and  ` theGunAnimation = TheGun.GetComponent<Animation>();` On a side-note,  is the value of `Time.deltaTime` fixed ? I know its meaning but is the value always equal to 0.5f ?

Comment: The value of `Time.deltaTime` is **not** fixed. Each frame can take different time depending on all the calculations that are done during that frame. Assuming an average frame rate of 60 fps this value will move around `1/60 ≈ 0.0167`. Since Update is called **every frame** this slowly reduces the timer over frames taking `0.5` real-time seconds. As said before the difference is that `if(!theGunAnimation)` checks if `theGunAnimation` is already referenced. If this is the case it skips the `GetComponent` because why work twice, if you already have a reference there is need for getting it again